# Can't get bootstrap grid to align properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap as a framework for my site and I'm having trouble getting the grid lined up correctly. I can't get it to align with the right edge (unless I increase the gutter - which breaks the whole page) despite my spans adding up. I'm really unsure were I'm going wrong so I'm hoping someone here can point me in the right direction.

The image below illustrates it well. I am trying to get the posts to align on the left and space themselves enough to fill the container width. I've tried increasing the gutter (which breaks the other spans on the page and drops the third post down onto a new line).

Each 'post' is inside a span4 div with a gutter width of 30px (I think this is default). I'm sure this is trivial but I've been staring at this issue for a few days now. The code for each post is:

```
<div class="span4">
  <div class="postcontainer">
    <div class="imgpostcontainer"> 
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php $url = the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $url ?>">
        </a>
    </div>
    <?php get_template_part('templates/content', get_post_format()); ?>
</div>
```

And the CSS that applies to the span is:

```
float: left;
margin-left: 30px;
min-height: 1px;
```

[image]

This can be seen in action here:

```
http://192.241.203.146/
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your class `wraps` and it's margin. Remove it and all fits, but I didn't look deeper. Gave you a clue.

Answer (score 1):

first; margin-left:30px is not default. default is 20px, but if you include responsive, it adjusts the margin property to 30px if clients screens width larger than 1200px.

second; bootstraps row consists total of 12 spans each. when I checked your code, you included more than 12 spans for one row.

about your problem; after opening a div with container, you directly used span class without initializing a row. all spans must be inside a row class. otherwise it will not work in order to be aligned, since a row starts with -20/30px margin on the left, while a span neutralizes that margin.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I've fixed the issue with not using rows, that was a mistake I made while trying to fix it. I've got 3x span 4's per row now but they still don't reach to the edge of the row div. It's as if the gutter isn't wide enough - but I can't change that or it moves everything since span gutter is global. Really not sure what I've done :(